# Bash script loop through subdirectories and write to file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I have no idea I have spent a lot of hours dealing with this problem. I need to write script. Script should loop recursively through subdirectories in current directory. It should check files count in each directory. If file count is greater than 10 it should write all names of these file in file named "BigList" otherwise it should write in file "ShortList". This should look like

```
---<directory name>
<filename>
<filename>
<filename>
<filename>
....
---<directory name>
<filename>
<filename>
<filename>
<filename>
....
```

My script only works if subdirecotries don't include subdirectories in turn. 
I am confused about this. Because it doesn't work as I expect. It will take less than 5 minutes to write this on any programming language for my. 
Please help to solve this problem , because I have no idea how to do this.
Here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
parent_dir=""
if [ -d "$1" ]; then
    path=$1;
else
    path=$(pwd)
fi
parent_dir=$path
loop_folder_recurse() { 
    local files_list=""      
    local cnt=0
    for i in "$1"/*;do
        if [ -d "$i" ];then
            echo "dir: $i"
            parent_dir=$i               
            echo before recursion
            loop_folder_recurse "$i"
            echo after recursion
            if [ $cnt -ge 10 ]; then
                echo -e "---"$parent_dir >> BigList
                echo -e $file_list >> BigList
            else
                echo -e "---"$parent_dir >> ShortList
                echo -e $file_list >> ShortList
            fi
        elif [ -f "$i" ]; then
            echo file $i
            if [ $cur_fol != $main_pwd ]; then
                file_list+=$i'\n'
                cnt=$((cnt + 1))
            fi
        fi
    done
}
echo "Base path: $path"
loop_folder_recurse $path
```

Comment: Your code is indented inscrutably and incomprehensibly.

Comment: Sorry for that, please help to do this without using find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this does what you want:

```
find . -type d -exec env d={} bash -c 'out=Shortlist; [ $(ls "$d" | wc -l) -ge 10 ] && out=Biglist; { echo "--$d"; ls "$d"; echo; } >>"$out"' ';'
```

If we don't want either to count subdirectories to the cut-off or to list them in the output, then use this version:

```
find . -type d -exec env d={} bash -c 'out=Shortlist; [ $(ls -p "$d" | grep -v "/$" | wc -l) -ge 10 ] && out=Biglist; { echo "--$d"; ls -p "$d"; echo; } | grep -v "/$" >>"$out"' ';'
```

Comment: Thanks for answer , but is it possible to do without calling find.

Comment: @ketazafor Yes, but `find` is the right tool for this job.

Comment: How can I write only files in file without directories ?

Comment: find ${find_path} -type d -exec env d={} bash -c 'out=Shortlist; [ $(ls -d "$d" | wc -l) -ge 10 ] && out=Biglist; { echo "--$d"; find "$d" -maxdepth 1 -type f; echo; } >>"$out"' ';'

Comment: @ketazafor Yours works well (although it still includes subdirectories in the size count)  I updated the answer with a slightly different approach.  The output format is slightly different so you may prefer one to the other based on that..